# Insert SQL in PDO from Select and data

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to make an insert in a table from php PDO and I have some problems since I am trying to use a select and another data at the same time.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO subscriptions(id_Event,pushToken,os)
                                                        :idOfEvent, (Select pushToken,os FROM users WHERE deviceUDID = :deviceUDID)");
            $stmt->execute(array(':deviceUDID' => $deviceUDID,':idOfEvent' => $idOfEvent));
```

But it says that I have a problem in my query. I don't know how to make an insert using selects and data at the same time.

Comment: You need to do error checking when running queries. There's [a whole chapter](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) in the manual. Please don't just copy a SQL fix from an answer and post again in the next syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the 3-year part. I'll remove the comment and improve its wording.

Comment: You've possibly obtained the syntax error from MySQL but you don't mention anything about it in your question and the code you've posted doesn't reveal whether you're doing proper error checking. Error messages are an awesome tool but many questions here reveal that it's often overlooked (or just plain ignored), thus my advice. You know, the teaching how to fish story ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the SQL query syntax, which is wrong. Try this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO subscriptions (id_Event, pushToken, os) 
                        SELECT :idOfEvent, pushToken, os 
                        FROM users 
                        WHERE deviceUDID = :deviceUDID");
$stmt->execute(array(':idOfEvent'   => $idOfEvent,
                     ':deviceUDID'  => $deviceUDID  ));
```

**EDIT**: Wrapped the query in your PHP code, just to be clear about the PDO parameters.

Comment: By doing this, idOfEvent should be in the same table as pushtoken and os, I have this field in a variable and not in the users table

Comment: Have you tried the query? You are passing `idOfEvent` as a constant in your query this way. Try to execute the query passing `:idOfEvent` parameter through PDO.

Comment: it works! thank you so much. I was wrong when I was trying to do it apart.